# Post-apocalyptic movie, non-English, with a depressing ending

Tags: identify-this-movie

Around five years ago I saw a pretty average post-apocalyptic, non-English (I think), movie with one of the most depressing endings I've seen.

But I can't remember the name and Google is failing me, so I'm trying my luck here.

I think it must be from late 1990's or early 2000.

Things I do remember from the movie:

- main character is male, possibly a bit slow in the head.
- it's set in a desert setting
- people are fighting over water, food and fuel
- female lead is a prostitute that joins the male lead
- male lead has or gets a dog companion
- they set out to search for some fabled Utopia where they still have power
- the ending is really depressing because:

  - the female lead gets killed (and possibly raped) by some guy offering food and fuel near the end
  - the male lead runs out of fuel and is forced to kill and eat his dog
  - the male lead finds the city, but is shot (either by an automated turret or a sniper)

Hope someone knows which movie this is, because the end makes it worth sitting through it.

Comment: Sounds a lot like one of the Mad Max ones, but I will look and see what I can find

Comment: Could be "A boy and his dog", but it's from 1975 and doesn't match completely...

Comment: I like that you are looking for a film that even you describe as 'pretty average'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Possibly ['Downstream'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downstream_%282010_film%29) (AKA *World's End*) from 2010 in which the hero also wanders around a post-apocalyptic, fuel-less world. From [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229236/combined):

> Wes Keller is a young man living in a world where oil has collapsed, the food supply has been wiped out, and cancer rates for women have skyrocketed, depleting the female population. In a barbaric environment where bio fuel, batteries, bullets and people are currency and marauders roam free, Wes tries to escape to a mythical world run on cold fusion "Plutopia", a place that may only exist in the mind.

He also ends up eating his dog, plus everyone dies at the end. It's US and in English, though. Here's the trailer:

Comment: That's most likely it!
You're my hero! I was beginning to wonder if I had dreamt this entire movie since no one else had heard about it.

Comment: @user8220 You might want to mark the answer as accepted if it is the correct solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mixed up the movies but this list might help:

http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EatTheDog

"A Boy and His Dog" has some similarities but there is a different twist in the end.

Comment: Already looked there and it's none of those, even though the movie I'm looking for would be perfect for that article.

And it's not A Boy and His Dog, but that one is what makes googling this so hard.

Comment: Yours was anime and not on the mark and you didn't skewered as bad as my good faith attempt :) so gonna delete mine, no good deed huh...