# Identifying a post-apocalyptic movie, perhaps about a world with no women, containing a memorable scene

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I am building up a collection of movies based in the future and there's one I saw about 20 years ago. However, I do not know how old the movie was when I saw it, so the best I can tell you is that it was produced at least 20 years ago.

**What do I recall about this movie?**

- It was set in the future (although whatever year in the future may not necessarily be 'our' future now.
- It was set in the United States, in some sort of post apocalyptic environment.
- This future may or may not have had women in it.

Let me explain the third bullet point to give some context, as there was at least one female character. I remember a scene in the movie that goes something like this:

> A man and woman (probably the main characters) come across some
>   location, seeking help I think, and when they get there the man they
>   are speaking to agrees to help them if he can have sex with the woman
>   *because they haven't seen a woman for a long time*. In the scene, the man accompanying the woman goes to attack the other man, but the woman
>   says it's alright, she'll do it. So she and the other man go into a
>   room and the only thing you see is her asking him "how do you want me"?
>   The movie then progresses from that point as if nothing happened.

So, this scene leads me to believe that women were rare in this post apocalyptic future.

I'm also hoping the above scene itself may be enough to identify the movie (usually you would see the woman getting out of this situation somehow - but in this one she just complies because they need his help!).  For this reason I believe this scene stands out from other movies.

**Other *possible* factors to help identify the movie are:**

- because it was set in the future, it may have been a science-fiction movie
- because it was set in the United States, it was probably an American movie

I have tried identifying this movie through other means, but have had no luck. One suggestion offered to me at another Stack Exchange site was that it may have been Waterworld. However, I can confirm this was not the movie.

Any suggestions?

Comment: A boy and his dog has this scene.

Comment: @cde Thanks for the suggestion. I will check this out and report back.

Comment: @cde I've checked out _A boy and his dog_ and this **isn't** the movie. Thank you again for the suggestion.

Comment: It's not *Zardoz*? I feel you'd remember that movie, but it does have some of the elements you mention…

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but no, this isn't the movie.

Comment: Similar question/movie description: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/post-apocalyptic-movie-non-english-with-a-depressing-ending

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan Similar yes, but unfortunately it's not the movie I'm looking for. :( Thanks for taking the time to check! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the movie you're talking about is [Waterworld (1995)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114898/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_29).

The women was not rare, instead the Drifter played by [Kim Coates](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0167649/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t32) had been out on the waters far too long.

Comment: I'm almost 100% certain.that it's not Waterworld, but I will check (as I haven't seen that movie since it came out, so who knows). But I don't recall the movie I'm talking about being based on the ocean at any stage.

Comment: Having just watched it, I can now confirm that Waterworld is not the movie. Thank you though for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Might it be ["Cherry 2000 (1987)"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092746/combined)?

Check out the [trailer here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kckEEQKXaCU) - the lady you might be referring to shows up at 1:37.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will check the movie out and report back.

Comment: Having just watched it, I can now confirm that Cherry 2000 is not the movie. Thank you though for bringing it to my attention!. :)